Flutter canvas drawing disappears when trying to zoom in/out
I have an app where the lines are drawn depending on numbers that user inputs and to the place where user taps. I have added buttons for zoom in and out in child field of my CustomPainter class. In there I am updating the _scaleFactor parameter which I then pass to the drawing class where it is used to make lines bigger or smaller. I also load an asset image and am not sure whether it affects my problem.
The problem is that every time I click on one of the buttons everything on the canvas indeed gets scaled and you can see it for a second but after that everything disappears and you can make it appear only by dragging finger on the screen (so GestureDetector widget starts working I guess).
This is my code:
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  static const PREFERENCES_IS_FIRST_LAUNCH_STRING =
      "PREFERENCES_IS_FIRST_LAUNCH_STRING";

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final myController1 = TextEditingController();
  final myController2 = TextEditingController();
  final myController3 = TextEditingController();
  final myController4 = TextEditingController();
  bool isComplete = false;
  int ratio1 = 10;
  int ratio2 = 10;
  int ratio3 = 10;
  int ratio4 = 10;
  double _progress1 = 0.0;
  late Animation<double> animation1;
  late AnimationController controller1;
  var tappedPoint = const Offset(0, 0);
  double _scaleFactor = 35.0;
  double _baseScaleFactor = 35.0;
  bool _dragging = false;
  var xPos = 0.0;
  var yPos = 0.0;

  int _numRoots = 0;
  final List<equations.Complex> _res = [];
  final List<int> _binRes = [];
  String _roots = "";
  bool shown = false;

  final GlobalKey run = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey input = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey xPoint = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey pOfX = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey keyNumRoots = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey drawing = GlobalKey();

  late Future<ui.Image> _imageFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _isFirstLaunch().then((result) {
        if (result) {
          ShowCaseWidget.of(context)
              .startShowCase([input, run, xPoint, pOfX, keyNumRoots, drawing]);
        }
      });
    });

    controller1 = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), vsync: this)
      ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          isComplete = true;
        } else {
          isComplete = false;
        }
      });

    animation1 = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(controller1)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _progress1 = animation1.value;
        });
      });

    _imageFuture = _loadImage("assets/images/turtle.png");
  }

  Future<bool> _isFirstLaunch() async {
    final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstLaunch = sharedPreferences
            .getBool(MyHomePage.PREFERENCES_IS_FIRST_LAUNCH_STRING) ??
        true;
    if (isFirstLaunch) {
      sharedPreferences.setBool(
          MyHomePage.PREFERENCES_IS_FIRST_LAUNCH_STRING, false);
    }
    return isFirstLaunch;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController1.dispose();
    myController2.dispose();
    myController3.dispose();
    myController4.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<ui.Image> _loadImage(String imagePath) async {
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes,
        targetHeight: 60, targetWidth: 60);
    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;

    return image;
  }

  onPan(double x, double y) {
    setState(() {
      tappedPoint =
          Offset(x, y);
      MyPainter.setScale(_scaleFactor.toInt());
    });
  }                    

  String calcDistance(String solution) {
    double p = MyPainter.getP();
    if (p.isNaN) {
      return "0";
    } else {
      if ((p.abs() <= 0.1) & (isComplete == true)) {
        if (_res.isNotEmpty) {
          bool found = false;
          int x = double.parse(solution).toInt();
          List<int> values = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < _res.length; i++) {
            values.add(_res[i].real.toInt());
          }
          int closestValue = getClosestValueInArray(values, x);
          for (int i = 0; i < _binRes.length; i++) {
            if ((_res[i].real.toInt() == closestValue) & (_binRes[i] == 0)) {
              _numRoots += 1;
              found = true;
              _binRes[i] = 1;
            }
          }
          if ((_numRoots == _binRes.length) & (shown == false)) {
            shown = true;
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
                toastification.show(
                    title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.allRoots),
                    style: ToastificationStyle.flatColored,
                    primaryColor: Colors.green,
                    autoCloseDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5)));
          }
          if (found) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
                toastification.show(
                    title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.congrats),
                    autoCloseDuration: const Duration(seconds: 3)));
          }
        }
      }
      return p.toStringAsFixed(5);
    }
  }                    

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Turtle Math"), actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => OnBoardingScreen()));
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.help_outline, color: Colors.white))
        ]),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: controller1,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, _) {
                    return Showcase(
                      key: input,
                      description: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.coefficients,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Spacer(flex: 1),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 5,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 50,
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                controller: myController1,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                decoration:
                                    const InputDecoration(hintText: "#1"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 5,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 50,
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                controller: myController2,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  // prefixIcon: const Icon(PiSymbol.pi_outline),
                                  hintText: "#2",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 5,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 50,
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                controller: myController3,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  // prefixIcon: const Icon(PiSymbol.pi_outline),
                                  hintText: "#3",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 5,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 50,
                              child: TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                controller: myController4,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  // prefixIcon: const Icon(PiSymbol.pi_outline),
                                  hintText: "#4",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Showcase(
                              key: run,
                              description:
                                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.startButton,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (myController1.text.isNotEmpty &
                                          myController2.text.isNotEmpty &
                                          myController3.text.isNotEmpty &
                                          myController4.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                        shown = false;
                                        _res.clear();
                                        _binRes.clear();
                                        _numRoots = 0;

                                        ratio1 = int.parse(myController1.text);
                                        ratio2 = int.parse(myController2.text);
                                        ratio3 = int.parse(myController3.text);
                                        ratio4 = int.parse(myController4.text);
                                        _roots = getRoots(
                                            myController1.text,
                                            myController2.text,
                                            myController3.text,
                                            myController4.text);

                                        controller1.reset();
                                        controller1.forward();
                                      } else {
                                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                content: Text(
                                                    AppLocalizations.of(
                                                            context)!
                                                        .error)));
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child:
                                      Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.run))),
                          const Spacer(
                              flex: 1), // child: Text(Platform.localeName)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                      getCoefficients(myController1.text, myController2.text,
                          myController3.text, myController4.text),
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Showcase(
                          key: xPoint,
                          description: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.xPoint,
                          child: Text(
                              "x = ${calcK(constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2)}",
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Showcase(
                          key: pOfX,
                          description: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.pOfX,
                          child: Text(
                              "p(x) = ${calcDistance(calcK(constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2))}",
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child:
                        // Text("$_roots ${_binRes.toString()} $_numRoots",
                        Showcase(
                      key: keyNumRoots,
                      description:
                          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.rootsDescription,
                      child: Text(
                          "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.numRoots} $_numRoots",
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    )),
                Expanded(
                    child: FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
                        future: _imageFuture,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.done) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              // scaling
                              onScaleStart: (details) {
                                _dragging = true;
                                _baseScaleFactor = _scaleFactor;
                              },
                              onScaleUpdate: (scaleDetails) {
                                if (scaleDetails.pointerCount == 3) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _scaleFactor =
                                        _baseScaleFactor * scaleDetails.scale;
                                  });
                                }
                                if (scaleDetails.pointerCount == 1) {
                                  onPan(scaleDetails.localFocalPoint.dx, scaleDetails.localFocalPoint.dy);
                                }
                                if (scaleDetails.pointerCount == 2) {
                                  if (_dragging) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      xPos += scaleDetails.focalPointDelta.dx;
                                      yPos += scaleDetails.focalPointDelta.dy;
                                    });
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              onScaleEnd: (scaleDetails) {
                                _dragging = false;
                              },
                              // onPanUpdate: (details) => onPan(details),
                              child: Showcase(
                                key: drawing,
                                description:
                                    AppLocalizations.of(context)!.drawing,
                                child: ClipRect(
                                  child: CustomPaint(
                                    painter: MyPainter(
                                        constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                                        constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                                        ratio1,
                                        ratio2,
                                        ratio3,
                                        ratio4,
                                        isComplete,
                                        _progress1,
                                        tappedPoint,
                                        xPos,
                                        yPos,
                                        snapshot.data),
                                    size: Size(constraints.maxWidth,
                                        constraints.maxHeight),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _scaleFactor =
                                                  _baseScaleFactor - 5; 
                                              MyPainter.setScale(_scaleFactor.toInt());                                             
                                            });
                                          },
                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.zoom_out),
                                          iconSize: 50,
                                        ),
                                        IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _scaleFactor =
                                                  _baseScaleFactor + 5;
                                              MyPainter.setScale(_scaleFactor.toInt());                                                                                        
                                            });
                                          },
                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.zoom_in),
                                          iconSize: 50,
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onScaleStart: (details) {
                                _baseScaleFactor = _scaleFactor;
                              },
                              onScaleUpdate: (scaleDetails) {
                                if (scaleDetails.pointerCount == 3) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _scaleFactor =
                                        _baseScaleFactor * scaleDetails.scale;
                                  });
                                }
                                if (scaleDetails.pointerCount == 1) {
                                  onPan(scaleDetails.localFocalPoint.dx, scaleDetails.localFocalPoint.dy);
                                }
                              },
                              child: CustomPaint(
                                  painter: MyPainter(
                                      constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                                      constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                                      ratio1,
                                      ratio2,
                                      ratio3,
                                      ratio4,
                                      isComplete,
                                      _progress1,
                                      tappedPoint,
                                      xPos,
                                      yPos),
                                  size: Size(constraints.maxWidth,
                                      constraints.maxHeight)),
                            );
                          }
                        })),
              ],
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  ui.Image? image;
  double _width = 0;
  static double _height = 0;
  static int _ratio1 = 0;
  static int _ratio2 = 0;
  static int _ratio3 = 0;
  static int _ratio4 = 0;
  static int _scale = 35;
  final double _progress;
  Offset tappedPoint;
  static bool _isComplete = false;
  static double k = 0;
  double _xPos = 0;
  double _yPos = 0;  

  MyPainter(width, height, ratio1, ratio2, ratio3, ratio4, isComplete,
      this._progress, this.tappedPoint, this._xPos, this._yPos,
      [this.image]) {
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    _ratio1 = ratio1;
    _ratio2 = ratio2;
    _ratio3 = ratio3;
    _ratio4 = ratio4;
    _isComplete = isComplete;
    // _scale = (_width / 10).toInt();
  }

  static void setScale(int newScale) {
    _scale = newScale;    
  }

  static double getP() {
    if (_isComplete == true) {
      return (_ratio4 - k * (_ratio3 - k * (_ratio2 - k * _ratio1))) / _scale;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  static double getK() {
    return k;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint linePaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 20
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    Paint solutionPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 8
      ..strokeCap = ui.StrokeCap.butt
      ..style = ui.PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = Colors.redAccent;

    Paint imaginaryPaint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..strokeCap = ui.StrokeCap.butt
      ..style = ui.PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = const Color.fromRGBO(105, 105, 105, 0.5);

    _ratio1 *= _scale;
    _ratio2 *= _scale;
    _ratio3 *= _scale;
    _ratio4 *= _scale;

    _width += _xPos;
    _height += _yPos;

    _width += (math.max(_ratio1, _ratio3) / 2) - _ratio1;
    _height += (math.max(_ratio2, _ratio4) / 2);

    var path = getPath();
    Rect bounds = path.getBounds();
    if (bounds.bottom >= size.height) {
      path = path
          .shift(Offset(0, -(bounds.bottom - _height + bounds.center.dy / 10)));
    }

    ui.PathMetrics pathMetrics = path.computeMetrics();

    ui.PathMetric pathMetric = pathMetrics.elementAt(0);
    final pos = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(pathMetric.length * _progress);
    Path extracted = pathMetric.extractPath(0.0, pathMetric.length * _progress);

    linePaint.strokeWidth = 6;

    canvas.drawPath(extracted, linePaint);
    if (image == null) {
      canvas.drawCircle(pos!.position, linePaint.strokeWidth / 2, linePaint);
    } else {
      Offset location = Offset(pos!.position.dx - image!.width / 2,
          pos.position.dy - image!.height / 2);
      canvas.save();
      double cx = pos.position.dx;
      double cy = pos.position.dy;
      double angle = pos.angle;
      if (angle == math.pi / 2) {
        angle = -angle;
      } else if (angle == -(math.pi / 2)) {
        angle = math.pi / 2;
      }
      rotateTurtle(canvas: canvas, cx: cx, cy: cy, angle: angle);
      canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points, [Offset(cx, cy)], linePaint);
      canvas.drawImage(image!, location, linePaint);
      canvas.restore();
      if (_isComplete) {
        // canvas.drawLine(Offset(_width, _height), tappedPoint, solutionPaint);
        k = (tappedPoint.dy - _height) / (_width - tappedPoint.dx);
        var solution = getSolution(k);
        double shift = 0;

        if (bounds.bottom >= size.height) {
          shift = (bounds.bottom - _height + bounds.center.dy / 10);
          solution = solution.shift(
              Offset(0, -(bounds.bottom - _height + bounds.center.dy / 10)));
        }

        // imaginary lines
        checkSolution(canvas, k, imaginaryPaint, extracted, shift);

        canvas.drawPath(solution, solutionPaint);
      }
    }
  }         

  Path getSolution(tangent) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(_width, _height)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio1, _height - tangent * _ratio1)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio1 - tangent * (_ratio2 - tangent * _ratio1),
          _height - _ratio2)
      ..lineTo(
          _width + _ratio1 - _ratio3,
          _height -
              _ratio2 +
              tangent * (_ratio3 - tangent * (_ratio2 - tangent * _ratio1)));
  }

  void rotateTurtle(
      {required Canvas canvas,
      required double cx,
      required double cy,
      required double angle}) {
    canvas.translate(cx, cy);
    canvas.rotate(angle);
    canvas.translate(-cx, -cy);
  }

  Path getPath() {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(_width, _height)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio1, _height)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio1, _height - _ratio2)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio1 - _ratio3, _height - _ratio2)
      ..lineTo(_width + _ratio1 - _ratio3, _height - _ratio2 + _ratio4);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant MyPainter oldDelegate) {
    return (oldDelegate._progress != _progress);  
  }
}

Could somebody please help me figure out why is this delay happening when zoom button is pressed? Thanks in advance.

post the code that can be directly run (without any external dependencies)

@pskink I'm not sure I'll be able to do that, I use images from assets in my drawings

what images have to do with that? what exactly you want to achieve with your painter?

@pskink basically what i want to do here is to change the scale value on button click. I use it in CustomPainter class to change size of the lines that are drawn. But everything disappears from canvas once i click the button.
